# What's wrong with exit command on my terminal?

Tags: command-line, su, exit

I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon. Somehow, the exit command isn't working. [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing's wrong. You were logged in as a root user. When you exited, your session was closed - but you opened this session as a user, so you get back to your user account.

It's kind of like opening full screen game - you open it from your desktop, and it looks like it took over your PC - yet when you close it, you go back to desktop - the place of origin - because you only closed your game, not the whole desktop.

Comment: Umm, Okay, but if I want to end the current session as the user and exit the terminal itself, what was I supposed to do?

Comment: Either type `exit` twice, or close terminal window - seems to be the easiest way to do it. You may also type `Ctrl+D` twice.